# Integral surface question please?

Tags: integration

We have 
$$\iint_D(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy.$$
Calculate its value where D is the zone limited by the lines $y^2=4ax$ and $x=a$.

Well so, I replace $x=a$ in $y^2=4ax$ and I have $y=4x^2$, so $y=\pm 2x$. But the problem is that I don't even know how to build a graph using this data, so I can calculate the limits... how to do this one?

Comment: It looks a lot like the unity circle, 1=x^2+y^2

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$y^2=4ax\implies x=\left(\frac y{2\sqrt a}\right)^2$$

This last is a horizontal parabola openning up towards the positive direction of the $\,x-$axis, and it intersects the line $\,x=a\,$ at $\,y=\pm 2a\,$ .

Your limits thus are

$$0\le x\le a\;,\;\;-2\sqrt{ax}\le y\le 2\sqrt{ax}$$

I'll leave it to you to find the limits with the reversed order of integration...

Comment: so now I will have to find $$\int_{0}^{a} \int_{-2*sqrt(a*x)}^{2*sqrt(a*x)} {f(x,y)}  dydx$$

Comment: Yes...if you want to do this in this order of integration.